# Compare in a loop adjacent array values, but only between even and odd adjacent keys (in that order)

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose these two arrays:

```
$variations = array(
    '100',
    '120',
    '140',
    '160',
    '180',
);

$variations = array(
    '100',
    '100',
    '120',
    '120',
    '140',
    '140',
);
```

I need to somehow distinguish between the two cases to calculate further things, so I have to compare 0 and 1 values together, 2 and 3, etc, to determine whether they are equal or not... So I did something like this:

```
foreach ( $variations as $o => $variation ) {
    if ( isset( $variation[$o + 1] /* this is just for the warning of the last value */) && $variation[$o] == $variation[$o + 1] ) {
        // do stuff here...
    } else {
        // do other stuff here
    }
}
```

However I noticed that this works well in half of the cases, because when `$o` becomes odd its value is different than `$o+1`'s value anyway, so we fall in the else clause...

Can someone help me figure out how to deal with this? Should I just also check when `$o` is odd or even and simply reverse what's happening in my current if/else check?

Comment: Please provide a clear [mcve].  What is your exact desired result?  Your question is a little misleading because you declare the same variable with two payloads.  I guess you mean that you are offering two different sample inputs.  Perhaps you should provide some clarity about that the "do stuff here" and "do other stuff here" is doing.  Depending on your conditional processing requirements, `array_map(fn($one, $two) => /* some stuff depending on if $two === null */, array_chunk($variations, 2))` may be appropriate.  Might you have `null` values in your input data?

Comment: Relevant: [php foreach as key, every two number as a group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6852550/2943403) and [How can I loop through an array in Php and get 3 items at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60132464/2943403) and [Selecting multiple array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9453040/2943403) and [Create subset of array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21985866/2943403) and [How to chunk an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30588821/2943403)

Comment: Regarding comparing each value to the next: [Comparing Next element inside foreach loop in associate array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66067739/2943403) and [Get next element in foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5096791/2943403) and [how to get next value in array loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22346934/2943403) and [How do I compare array value to the next value in array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20428161/2943403) and [PHP - get array value if next element is not series](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50572952/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your approach to checking for pairs of elements by incrementing $o by 2 instead of 1 in each iteration of the **foreach loop.**

```
foreach ($variations as $o => $variation) {
    if ($o % 2 == 0 && isset($variations[$o + 1]) && $variation == $variations[$o + 1]) {
        // your code goes here
    } else {
        // your code goes here
    }
}
```

> for that you just ensure that the elements you compare in each
> iteration are always a pair.

Comment: That's what I had done, but I had put the even condition at the end of the `if()` check. like  so `if ( isset( $variation[$o + 1] && $variation[$o] == $variation[$o + 1] && ( $o & 1 )  )` and it did what I mentioned in my original post. Does the position of the condition play a role? In other words, I had put the check last, and you put it first...